# Is it possible to templatize the class name in a C++ class declaration?

Tags: c++, class, templates

To cut down on repeating myself-- and without needing to resort to `#define`-- I would like to do something like the following:

```
template <class T>
class T final: public Base
{
public:
  T();
  virtual ~T();

private:
  void method1(T const& that);
  const T* method2(char const*);  // was pure-virtual in Base
};
```

On the one hand, I'm fearful this is disallowed since the above template has no name of its own to invoke it by:

```
typedef ???<DerivedFOO> DerivedFOO;
```

but on the other hand, I understand that C++ templates are themselves a Turing-complete language, so maybe there is some way to do this that isn't too heinously convoluted?

- Answering with "using `#define` is the least-obfuscated way to accomplish your needs" would be accepted by me if that ends up being the most compelling answer.
- I am stuck with C++11, presently.  But answers dependent on newer iterations of the language would still be accepted (I will accept the answer that seems best for the general audience, even if my own needs require something else.)

Comment: I have to ask: why do you want to do this? In programming languages you can ask: what's in a name? Changing the name of a variable, class, etc, consistently, does not impact how the program runs. Unless of course you are using reflection. But C++ has nearly zero reflection in it. So I don't see the purpose. Maybe if you added the code where repetition actually occurs, it would be clearer? You claim that repetition is an issue but I don't see how exactly.

Comment: I'm going to agree with @NirFriedman. The question is vague. Don't quite understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Fair question.  I have 3 classes that will all have the same interface, but different implementations.  I want the compiler to consider them to be different types.  I want to avoid having essentially the same class declaration in my header file, 3 times.  (Just trying to keep it DRY, really.)   Until dwwork's answer, I thought the only variant I had to parameterize the template on was the name of the derived class.  But it turns out that one of my methods is Type(), which returns a unique enum value for each different DerivedFOO, so I may have my solution.

Comment: @RyanV.Bissell If the implementations are completely different, I can't really recommend the solution with templating on an enum. In exchange for saving a small amount of boilerplate (just the declaration, not even the definition which is different anyhow), you're entering into the land template specializializations, which has weird edge cases. For instance, you can no longer have a template function member (you can't have an unspecialized template member function of a fully specialized class).

Comment: Thanks for the comments.   I'm re-thinking this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Does this sort of accomplish what you want?

```
enum NAMES 
{
    NAME1,
    NAME2,
    ....
};

template<int Name>
class Derived : public Base
{
...
};
```

And would be used as:

```
Derived<NAME1> a;
```

Comment: That is an interesting idea, since my actual classes (not example one above) are strongly associated with enum-class values.   I'll play with the idea later.

Comment: I will say that if you still have to implement each class separately, (as a template specialization), then it won't buy you much. If, however, you can somehow base the behavior of the classes on the enum (through the use of helper structs, and other meta-template techniques) then this could maybe save you some lines of code.

Comment: I don't love this solution, but if you're going to go this way, at least template on the enum itself `template <NAMES name>`. And make it an `enum class`. That way you can't do `Derived<0> a`. And also the names will be scoped making things clearer: `Derived<NAMES::NAME1> a;

Comment: Yes, mine is an `enum class`.  Although, I am rethinking this entire approach, due to your comments on my question.